how to reset asmb8-ikvm firewall
Due to a misconfiguration of the firewall, I am currently unable to access the IPMI of the local server（Asus p10s-i）.
When executing ipmicfg -fd 2, I receive the error message "command not supported". Are there any other methods to reset the firewall?
